# Error org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot inject @Test annotated Method main with class Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, testng, testng-eclipse

I have created a testng.xml file to run a suite of my selenium webdriver test. From eclipse I can run this just fine as a testNG Suite, but from the command like I get the following error.

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">; 
  <suite name="CATS Regression Suite"> 
    <test name="WEB UI"> 
      <parameter name="uid" value="TestAccount"/> 
      <parameter name="pid" value="Test123"/> 
      <classes> 
         <class name="VerifyLogin"/> 
      </classes> 
     </test> 
    <!-- Test --> 
  </suite> 
  <!-- Suite -->
```

command ran:

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Exception trace:

```
[Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [main] with [class [Ljava.lang.String;].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1293)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1020)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1110)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)

at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1434)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1403)
```

Code (As shared in the comments)

```
public class VerifyLogin extends TestBase {
   @Parameters({"uid","pid"}) 
   @Test 
   public void verifyLogin(String uid, String pid) throws IOException, Exception {
      String userName = uid;
      String passWord = pid; 
      // new instance 
      ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\AdvancedReport.html", true); 
      //starting test 
      ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Login Test", "Regression"); 
      // log step 
      test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Browser Running"); 
      TestBase login=new TestBase(); 
      login.testLogin(userName, passWord);
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the signature of your test method look like? It looks like it's expecting a string and not getting it.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="CATS Regression Suite">
  <test name="WEB UI">
    <parameter name="uid" value="TestAccount"/>
   <parameter name="pid" value="Test123"/>
     <classes>
   <class name="VerifyLogin"/>
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: You are not using the same testng version between the command line and eclipse. Check it.

Comment: so it's a data driven test? What does your actual method signature look like? It would be something like 
`@Test
public void main()`. Normally I wouldn't name a test `main()`, but just for clarity your error seems to be referring to a test called `main`, not to be confused with a program's `main` method.

Comment: public class VerifyLogin extends TestBase
{
 @Parameters({"uid", "pid"})
 @Test
 public void verifyLogin(String uid, String pid) throws IOException, Exception
 {
  String userName = uid;
  String passWord = pid;
  // new instance
  ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\AdvancedReport.html", true);
  
  //starting test
  ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Login Test", "Regression");
  
  // log step
  test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Browser Running");
    
  TestBase login=new TestBase();
  
  login.testLogin(userName, passWord);

Comment: @CJ2K - I have extracted the code that you shared and included it in your question after editing it. It still is not complete. You would need to show us the complete code include the import statements. I have a gut feel that you perhaps might be mixing up JUnit and TestNG annotations.

Comment: @CJ2K Do you have that `@Test` annotation where it shouldn't be? Specifically somewhere you have a `main` method? Maybe the issue isn't in your `verifyLogin` test

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `String uid`, `String pid` in main method and run once again as

```
public void verifyLogin(String uid, String pid)
```

to

```
public void verifyLogin()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give parameters in @Test method, then you need to provide valid data provider.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).